# Why does Magento CSV translation file seem to work only sporadically?

Tags: magento, translation

How come this line doesn't translate in translate.csv file? The translate.csv file is located in the correct place and works most of the time but on a few places like below it doesn't work. How come it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't?

My csv file is in UTF-8 in the app\design\frontend\spanish\default\locale\es_ES directory.

```
<div class="block" id="creare-container">
          <div class="block-title"> <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Need it Quick?') ?></span></strong> </div>
```

This module doesn't have and translation module csv in the app\locale directory either.

Thanks

Comment: One possible reason: Magento keeps a cache of the translation strings, so if you add new translation and the cache feature is enabled, you have to refresh the translations cache to see the result. Another possible reason: I found odd behavior with translation strings, that aren't enclosed with quotes in the CSV file. Can you please edit your question and to add short snippet of your CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

In the `echo` you have Small letters:

```
$this->__('Need it Quick?')
```

You need to use the same to the translation CSV file

just change a line in CSV file from:
**"NEED IT QUICK?","NEED IT RÁPIDO?"**

to:
**"Need it Quick?","NEED IT RÁPIDO?"**

Answer (score 1):

you have to write exact the same thing what you have write within php tag..
just copy that exact thing, put it in your tr

Answer (score 1):

Some strings are translated at multiple files from app/locale, like "Add to Cart" (`Mage_Catalog.csv`, `Mage_Sales.csv`, `Mage_Checkout.csv`). This can cause troubles with overwriting them in your theme translate.csv file.

In these cases it will be helpfull to specify which translation file from app/locale should be overwritten in your translate.csv file, e.g.:

```
"Mage_Catalog::Add to Cart","Translation"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but I didn't have room.

I have my cache disabled. Here is the line in my CSV file:

```
"NEED IT QUICK?","NEED IT RÁPIDO?"
```

it's exactly the same as the the ones that work. Here is the whole file, not much in it because I was having to add special code for the html entities until I found i had to save it in UTF-8 :) so I was redoing it correctly. Anyway here it is:

```
"Most Viewed Items","Artículos Mas Vistos"
"Your Billing Information","Tu información de facturación"
"Special Angels","Angels Especiales"
"NEED IT QUICK?","NEED IT RÁPIDO?"
```

Actually, the Most Viewed Items doesn't translate either. I've changed the wording too just to test it in case there was some conflict.

Comment: Can you not move it to app/locale/es_ES/ directory. I am just wondering if it is not translating b/c it looks there first.

Comment: Hmm ... regarding the "Most Viewed Items". Keep in mind, that the translation functionality is case sensitive. For example "NEED IT QUICK?" can be rendered from your browser with uppercase ( because of css rule: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp ),  but actually to be "Need it quick?" ... One more hint is always to check the string in the .phtml file, so don't trust of the output, that you have in your browser. Good luck.

Comment: That was it. It was in small case in the template file. I'll have to remember that. Thanks